# Three.js Custom Shader

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl, three.js

> Note that much of this code as changed as of edit 3 below.

So I really like a blog post by Brandon Jones ([found here](http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/08/more-gpu-tile-map-demos-zelda.html)). I wanted to convert his code to Three.js, but I am having some issues. You can find his full code [here](http://media.tojicode.com/zelda/lttp.html). Here is my attempt so far, with a couple comments for questions I have:

```
// Shader
var tilemapVS = [
    "attribute vec2 pos;",
    "attribute vec2 texture;",

    "varying vec2 pixelCoord;",
    "varying vec2 texCoord;",

    "uniform vec2 viewOffset;",
    "uniform vec2 viewportSize;",
    "uniform vec2 inverseTileTextureSize;",
    "uniform float inverseTileSize;",

    "void main(void) {",
    "   pixelCoord = (texture * viewportSize) + viewOffset;",
    "   texCoord = pixelCoord * inverseTileTextureSize * inverseTileSize;",
    "   gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0, 1.0);",
    "}"
].join("\n");

var tilemapFS = [
    "precision highp float;",

    "varying vec2 pixelCoord;",
    "varying vec2 texCoord;",

    "uniform sampler2D tiles;",
    "uniform sampler2D sprites;",

    "uniform vec2 inverseTileTextureSize;",
    "uniform vec2 inverseSpriteTextureSize;",
    "uniform float tileSize;",
    "uniform int repeatTiles;",

    "void main(void) {",
    "   if(repeatTiles == 0 && (texCoord.x < 0.0 || texCoord.x > 1.0 || texCoord.y < 0.0 || texCoord.y > 1.0)) { discard; }",
    "   vec4 tile = texture2D(tiles, texCoord);",
    "   if(tile.x == 1.0 && tile.y == 1.0) { discard; }",
    "   vec2 spriteOffset = floor(tile.xy * 256.0) * tileSize;",
    "   vec2 spriteCoord = mod(pixelCoord, tileSize);",
    "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(sprites, (spriteOffset + spriteCoord) * inverseSpriteTextureSize);",
    //"   gl_FragColor = tile;",
    "}"
].join("\n");

this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    attributes: {
        //not really sure what to use here, he uses some quadVertBuffer
        //for these values, but not sure how to translate.
        pos: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
        texture: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) }
    },
    uniforms: {
        viewportSize: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(viewport.width() / this.tileScale, viewport.height() / this.tileScale) },
        inverseSpriteTextureSize: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(1/tileset.image.width, 1/tileset.image.height) },
        tileSize: { type: 'f', value: this.tileSize },
        inverseTileSize: { type: 'f', value: 1/this.tileSize },

        tiles: { type: 't', value: tilemap },
        sprites: { type: 't', value: tileset },

        viewOffset: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(Math.floor(0), Math.floor(0)) },
        inverseTileTextureSize: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(1/tilemap.image.width, 1/tilemap.image.height) },
        //is 'i' the correct type for an int?
        repeatTiles: { type: 'i', value: 1 }
    },
    vertexShader: tilemapVS,
    fragmentShader: tilemapFS,
    transparent: false
});

/*this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xCC0000
})*/

this.plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(
    tilemap.image.width * this.tileSize * this.tileScale, //width
    tilemap.image.height * this.tileSize * this.tileScale//, //height
    //tilemap.image.width * this.tileScale, //width-segments
    //tilemap.image.height * this.tileScale //height-segments
);

this.plane.dynamic = true;

this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.plane, this.material);
```

Once I load the page I get the following error:

```
TypeError: v1 is undefined
    customAttribute.array[ offset_custom ] = v1.x;
```

I'm sure this has to do with how I set the attributes, but i'm not sure what they should be. Any help is appreciated as there is little to no documentation on Custom Shaders in Three.js.

**EDIT**: Here is the code used in the blog post to fill the 2 attributes of the vertex shader (`pos`, and `texture`):

```
//in ctor
var quadVerts = [
    //x  y  u  v
    -1, -1, 0, 1,
     1, -1, 1, 1,
     1,  1, 1, 0,

    -1, -1, 0, 1,
     1,  1, 1, 0,
    -1,  1, 0, 0
];

this.quadVertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.quadVertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(quadVerts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

this.tilemapShader = GLUtil.createProgram(gl, tilemapVS, tilemapFS);

//...

//then on the draw method
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.quadVertBuffer);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader.attribute.position);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader.attribute.texture);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.attribute.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.attribute.texture, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
```

I really don't fully understand exactly what is happening here, but if I am correct I think it is filling 2 `Float32Array`s with half the data of the `quadVertBuffer` in each. Not only am I not sure why, I am not sure if I'm correct, nor do I know how t convert this to the Three.js method.

---

**EDIT2**: Right now I am using a plane to display the (2D) background, should I be using a sprite instead?

---

**EDIT3**:

So I got a little farther when I realized that Three.js will set position and uv vectors for me (which seems to be similar if not the same as position/texture in the above example). I also noticed that I may have had some types wrong since many of the `'v2'` types I had (which invoke `uniform2f`) were actually being loaded via `uniform2fv`, so I changed those to `'v2v'` and updated the value. Now I don't get the error, and it does paint *something*, just not quite the tilemap.

Here is the updated Vertex Shader:

```
var tilemapVS = [
    "varying vec2 pixelCoord;",
    "varying vec2 texCoord;",

    "uniform vec2 viewOffset;",
    "uniform vec2 viewportSize;",
    "uniform vec2 inverseTileTextureSize;",
    "uniform float inverseTileSize;",

    "void main(void) {",
    "   pixelCoord = (uv * viewportSize) + viewOffset;",
    "   texCoord = pixelCoord * inverseTileTextureSize * inverseTileSize;",
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);",
    "}"
].join("\n");
```

and the updated Shader Material:

```
this._material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        viewportSize: { type: 'v2v', value: [new THREE.Vector2(viewport.width() / this.tileScale, viewport.height() / this.tileScale)] },
        inverseSpriteTextureSize: { type: 'v2v', value: [new THREE.Vector2(1/tileset.image.width, 1/tileset.image.height)] },
        tileSize: { type: 'f', value: this.tileSize },
        inverseTileSize: { type: 'f', value: 1/this.tileSize },

        tiles: { type: 't', value: tilemap },
        sprites: { type: 't', value: tileset },

        viewOffset: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(0, 0) },
        inverseTileTextureSize: { type: 'v2v', value: [new THREE.Vector2(1/tilemap.image.width, 1/tilemap.image.height)] },
        repeatTiles: { type: 'i', value: 1 }
    },
    vertexShader: tilemapVS,
    fragmentShader: tilemapFS,
    transparent: false
});
```

And here is the result that I get:

[image]

Any ideas are welcome!

---

**EDIT 4**:

If I change the Vertex shader to use what I have found to be the "Three.js method" of setting `gl_Position` I can get even closer, but the offset is wrong in the sprite sheet. I think the `pixelCoord` varying is set wrong (since `uv` has slightly different values than `texture` I think).

I changed the Vertex Shader's main function to:

```
void main(void) {
   pixelCoord = (uv * viewportSize) + viewOffset;
   texCoord = pixelCoord * inverseTileTextureSize * inverseTileSize;
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

and now I get actual tiles form the texture sheet, but the actual tile it chooses is wrong:

[image]

getting closer, any help is still appreciated.

---

**EDIT 5**:

I suspect this will be my last update, as I am close to having an answer. After setting `tileset.flipY = false;`, where tileset is the actual texture tiles, not the red map. I get all the right tiles landing in the right places; except they are all upside down!

Here is what it looks like after this change:

[image]

Is there some way to flip each individual texture over the Y axis (without editing the tileset image)? I feel like there is some simple vector math I could add to my shader to flip each texture it draws and finalize this.

I do note that if I don't flip both (`tilemap.flipY = false;` and `tileset.flipY = false;`) I get the right textures, int the right spots, fitting together correctly. But the **entire map is upside down!** so close...

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could share a link to *your* full code? Even better if you have a working link where we can debug the error.

Comment: @mrdoob Sure, https://github.com/englercj/lttp-webgl is the code. You can just clone it and open the index.html. Select "Load Resources" then Select "Launch Game". The code in question can be found mainly in `js/game/lib/core/TileMap.js`, which is instantiated and added to the scene in `js/game/lib/core/Engine.js`. All the properties in the `resources` object are `THREE.Texture`s loaded with `THREE.TextureLoader`. Thanks!

Comment: I also have brandon's code in there as well for reference, though they are not used (they are prefixed with `brandons_`).

Comment: @mrdoob The code base has been change significantly since you last asked for it. You should be able to get all the information you need from edits 4 and 5, however if you still need the full code it is up-to-date on that github link. I am working off the master branch currently.

Comment: @mrdoob Is there a clean way to use gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL with Three.js? (Or if it's already there, possibly to turn it off?) That may solve his problem.

Comment: @Toji that is what the `.flipY` properties (that I am setting to false) do. From `_gl.pixelStorei( _gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, texture.flipY );` but the resulting texture is still upside down. If I don't set this flag on both the `tilemap` and `tileset` textures, then the maps don't line up and incorrect textures are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this "working" although I do not consider it "fixed".

I flipped the tilemap (`tilemap.flipY = true`), unflipped the tileset (`tileset.flipY = false`) and then modified the `mapmaker.html` (that Toji wrote that will create these tilemaps) to draw each tile *upside down on the sprite sheet (tileset)*.

I would MUCH prefer a different answer that actually fixes the problem instead of working around it like this, but for now this is my solution.

Below is the full relevant code.

Shader:

```
var tilemapVS = [
    "varying vec2 pixelCoord;",
    "varying vec2 texCoord;",

    "uniform vec2 viewOffset;",
    "uniform vec2 viewportSize;",
    "uniform vec2 inverseTileTextureSize;",
    "uniform float inverseTileSize;",

    "void main(void) {",
    "    pixelCoord = (uv * viewportSize) + viewOffset;",
    "    texCoord = pixelCoord * inverseTileTextureSize * inverseTileSize;",
    "    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
    "}"
].join("\n");

var tilemapFS = [
    //"precision highp float;",

    "varying vec2 pixelCoord;",
    "varying vec2 texCoord;",

    "uniform sampler2D tiles;",
    "uniform sampler2D sprites;",

    "uniform vec2 inverseTileTextureSize;",
    "uniform vec2 inverseSpriteTextureSize;",
    "uniform float tileSize;",
    "uniform int repeatTiles;",

    "void main(void) {",
    "    vec4 tile = texture2D(tiles, texCoord);", //load this pixel of the tilemap
    "    if(tile.x == 1.0 && tile.y == 1.0) { discard; }", //discard if R is 255 and G is 255
    "    vec2 spriteOffset = floor(tile.xy * 256.0) * tileSize;", //generate the offset in the tileset this pixel represents
    "    vec2 spriteCoord = mod(pixelCoord, tileSize);",
    "    vec4 texture = texture2D(sprites, (spriteOffset + spriteCoord) * inverseSpriteTextureSize);",
    "    gl_FragColor = texture;",
    "}"
].join("\n");
```

Shader Material (where `tilemap` and `tileset` are `THREE.Texture`s):

```
//Setup Tilemap
tilemap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
tilemap.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter;
if(this.repeat) {
    tilemap.wrapS = tilemap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
} else {
    tilemap.wrapS = tilemap.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
}

//Setup Tileset
tileset.wrapS = tileset.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
tileset.flipY = false;
if(this.filtered) {
    tileset.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    tileset.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
} else {
    tileset.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    tileset.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapNearestFilter;
}

//setup shader uniforms
this.offset = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
this._uniforms = {
    viewportSize: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(viewport.width / this.tileScale, viewport.height / this.tileScale) },
    inverseSpriteTextureSize: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(1/tileset.image.width, 1/tileset.image.height) },
    tileSize: { type: 'f', value: this.tileSize },
    inverseTileSize: { type: 'f', value: 1/this.tileSize },

    tiles: { type: 't', value: tilemap },
    sprites: { type: 't', value: tileset },

    viewOffset: { type: 'v2', value: this.offset },
    inverseTileTextureSize: { type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(1/tilemap.image.width, 1/tilemap.image.height) },
    repeatTiles: { type: 'i', value: this.repeat ? 1 : 0 }
};

//create the shader material
this._material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: this._uniforms,
    vertexShader: tilemapVS,
    fragmentShader: tilemapFS,
    transparent: false
});

this._plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(viewport.width, viewport.height, this.tileSize, this.tileSize);

this._mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this._plane, this._material);
```

Modified Mapmaker portion:

```
MapMaker.prototype.processTile = function(x, y) {
    //rotate upside down, and draw
    this.tileCtx.save();
    this.tileCtx.translate(0, this.tileSize);
    this.tileCtx.scale(1, -1);
    this.tileCtx.drawImage(this.srcImage, 
        x * this.tileSize, y * this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileSize, 
        0, 0, this.tileSize, this.tileSize);

    var sprite = this.cacheSprite();

    this.tileCtx.restore();

    this.mapCtx.fillStyle="rgb(" + sprite.x + "," + sprite.y + ", 0)";
    this.mapCtx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);

    /* Why was this thing drawing 2 times?
    this.tileCtx.drawImage(this.srcImage, 
        x * this.tileSize, y * this.tileSize, this.tileSize, this.tileSize, 
        0, 0, this.tileSize, this.tileSize);*/
};
```

If anyone has a different answer, please do not be shy to post it.